# Proper use of words Blessed or Blest

Tags: verbs

Which of the following is grammatically correct

```
              A life blessed by God  

                     or 

               A life blest by God
```

My research just gets me more confused.

Comment: They are both correct, but *blest* is archaic.

Comment: Nevertheless, on ELU it is considered proper to show what research you have done.

Answer (score 2):

For modern usage, use **blessed** (pronounced like "blest"). The word *blest* is not incorrect, it's just an archaic form.

From [grammarist.com](http://grammarist.com/spelling/blessed-blest/):

> Blessed is the past tense and past participle of bless. Blest is an
>   archaic form that shows up mainly in references to old, mostly
>   poetical texts and as a poetic affectation. Elsewhere, it has been
>   pushed out of the language. This is the case throughout the
>   English-speaking world.
>
> Both spellings descend from older forms in Old and Middle English, and
>   both developed around the  14th century,1 though blessed is probably a
>   little older. Blessed is one of a number of -ed words that gained a -t
>   variant when the vowel sound in -ed was dropped around the 16th
>   century.2 Blest was never more common than blessed, though, and today
>   we remember it mainly because it appears in some great literary works
>   of the early modern era. Shakespeare, for example, used it a few dozen
>   times (at least in the early renderings of his plays, which were
>   assembled by several people with different spelling preferences, and
>   where blessed is actually about twice as common as blest). It is
>   probably significant that in our searches for historical examples of
>   the two forms, most instances of blest are in poetry. Blessed,
>   meanwhile, is disproportionately common in Christian texts.
>
> The old, two-syllable pronunciation of blessed (bless-id) survives in
>   religious oratory and in some religious phrases, but elsewhere the
>   word’s ending is pronounced like that of other words ending in
>   -essed—that is, est instead of ess-id.

Comment: It's not just a "poetic affectation." Blest was used by Shakespeare and other poets because that way people would know not to pronounce it bless-id, and their verses would scan. If you're writing poetry, by all means feel free to use *blest*. Otherwise, use *blessed* and let people pronounce it however they want.